# how to remove the err msg. Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I need help about this  error that I  continuously getting msg:  Subscript out of range.
When I debug   is taken me to this line:
Set ws1 = s1.Sheets(Counter + 1)
Set ws2 = s2.Sheets(Counter + 1)
how can I resolve this?  without getting that error?  My output result are correct but I want to rid of that error msg? any idea?

Here is the code:

```vb
Sub Compare_Two_Excel_Sheets()
    'Define Fields
    Dim Flag As Double
  
    Dim iR As Double, iC As Double, oRw As Double
    Dim iRow_M As Double, iCol_M As Double
    Dim s1 As Workbook, s2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim s3 As Workbook
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim MyFile2 As String
    'List NameShate
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Counter   As Integer
    
    Counter = 0 ' for the sheetsName
    Flag = 0 '  for the differences
    
    MyFile = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("vba").Range("C3")
    MyFile2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("vba").Range("C4")

    Set s1 = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
    Set s2 = Workbooks.Open(MyFile2)
     
    Set ws3 = s2.Sheets.Add(After:=s2.Worksheets(s2.Worksheets.Count))
    ws3.Name = "DETAILS"
    
   
 For Each ws In s2.Worksheets
    ActiveCell.Offset(Counter, 0).Value = ws.Name

    Set ws1 = s1.Sheets(Counter + 1)
   
    Set ws2 = s2.Sheets(Counter + 1)
    
    iRow_M = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    iCol_M = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    
    For iR = 1 To iRow_M
    For iC = 1 To iCol_M
        ws1.Cells(iR, iC).Interior.Color = xlNone
        ws2.Cells(iR, iC).Interior.Color = xlNone
        
        If ws1.Cells(iR, iC) <> ws2.Cells(iR, iC) Then
           ws1.Cells(iR, iC).Interior.Color = vbYellow
           ws2.Cells(iR, iC).Interior.Color = vbYellow
           
           oRw = oRw + 1
           ws3.Cells(oRw, 2) = ws2.Cells(iC)
           ws3.Cells(oRw, 3) = ws1.Cells(iR, iC)
           ws3.Cells(oRw, 4) = ws2.Cells(iR, iC)
           Flag = Flag + 1
        End If
        
    Next iC
    Next iR
    
     Counter = Counter + 1
 Next ws
```

Comment: If your workbook doesn't have `Counter + 1` sheets then what should be the outcome?  Are the workbooks supposed to have the same number of sheets?  Where are you initializing `Counter` ?

Comment: Hi Tim Williams,
thanks for helping me..
actually I have  two excel with multiple worksheets.. 
example in Excel 1 I have sheet 1, sheet2 , sheet 3 , i
in Excel 2 I have also sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3.. I wanted to compare sheet1 with sheet1 and go to the next sheet2= sheet2.  That I need counter to go  to he next sheet.
here is the all code:

Comment: Yes I initialize above the code:   
 Dim Counter   As Integer
    Counter = 0 ' for the sheetsName

Comment: And where are you incrementing `Counter`/  A more-complete code listing would be useful here.

Comment: I update above the first comment.
You can find all code there

Comment: You first need to test if `s1.Sheets.Count = s2.Sheets.Count`  Otherwise you get an error when s1 has fewer sheets than s2

Comment: If initially workbooks S1 and S2 have  the same sheets, so **s1.Sheets.Count = s2.Sheets.Count**, you add sheet "DETAILS" to s2 and then **s1.Sheets.Count = s2.Sheets.Count-1**. An error will definitely occur.  See Set ws3 = s2.Sheets.Add(After:=s2.Worksheets(s2.Worksheets.Count))
    ws3.Name = "DETAILS"

Comment: tnx  good  people,  I resolve this with this  code: For Each ws In s1.Worksheets
   If SheetExists(s2, ws.Name) = False Then
    If sMissingSheets <> "" Then sMissingSheets = sMissingSheets & ","
        sMissingSheets = sMissingSheets & ws.Name